# What is the best way of resetting a struct members to initial values?

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct which is initialized as below:

```
struct MmlFault {
    std::string faultDescription{""};
    MmlFaultType mmlFaultType{MmlFaultType::INVALID_ERROR};
};
```

I set its parameters as below:

```
MmlFault myFault;
myFault.faultDescription = "bla bla";
myFault.mmlFaultType = MmlFaultType::BIG_ERROR;
```

What is the best way of resetting a struct members to initial values?

**Note: I believe there is no better answer than using constructor**

Comment: Since you disallow `myFault = MmlFault{};` using the constructor, you'll have to do it yourself `myFault.faultDescription = ""; myFault.mmlFaultType = MmlFaultType::INVALID_ERROR;`

Comment: Why without a constructor?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I would rather ask what does he mean by _without a constructor_. Since he wants to change an already constructed variable, he can't construct it again even if he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why using constructors is not cool, but you can try other things.
If you don't want to assign with a temporary object(`myFault = MmlFault{}`),
you have to do it manually somewhere.

1. Make a function

```
void reset(MmlFault& mm) {
  mm.faultDescription = "";
  mm.mmlFaultType = ...
}

reset(myFault);
```

2. Member function

```
struct MmlFault {
    constexpr static const char* init1 = "";
    constexpr static MmlFaultType init2 = MmlFaultType::INVALID_ERROR;

    std::string faultDescription = init1;
    MmlFaultType mmlFaultType = init2;

    void reinitialize() {
      faultDescription = init1;
      mmlFaultType = init2;
    }
};
```

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for your comment